# search for two relationships at once

Tags: contacts, search, relationships

is it possible to search for two relationships at once?

Until now I search for relations like
- search
- advanced search
- relationships
- choose the desired relationships

thx.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail about exactly what you are trying to do.  This would help people to make useful suggestions.  Please also include the version of CiviCRM you are using and the CMS system.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using search builder, not advanced search.

Comment: thx barbara. search  builder cant search two relationships according to my knowledge

Comment: I want to look up two or more relationships in one step. with advanced search i can only l search for 1 realtionship at the same time.

and sometimes i want to establish an smart group with these 2 or 3 relationships. thx

Comment: Oliver,
You're correct, I was confusing relationships with activities in search builder. What about using advanced search to create individual smaller groups based on relationship type, then using the custom search include exclude groups to search for the combination set you need And then create the final smart group from that